# Should I be worried about Ignoring query from non-local network in dnsmasq?

Tags: dns, confidentiality, dnsmasq

I am using a DNS forwarder, it's not open to the WWW (runs only in the LAN) and in the `dnsmasq` logs I noticed something off:

```
Ignoring query from non-local network
```

Has my network been breached?

Dnsmasq is running on Pi-Hole with most of the logging disabled. I know, I kind of shot myself in the foot there.

All of the info I found is here, but it doesn't help me debug: https://docs.pi-hole.net/ftldns/dnsmasq_warn/